# How to handle every socket response in SailsJS?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, sails.js, sails.io.js

In SailsJS every socket response contains JWR headers. How I can inject my custom header in every socket response ?

Answer (score 0):

`router:route` event in Sails can solve this problem:

```
sails.on('router:route', (route) => {

    var { req: request, res: response } = route;

    // Send `Lifted-At` header to client
    if (request.isSocket) {
        response.set('Lifted-At', sails.config.liftedAt.toUTCString());
    }
});
```